# Node Webkit - Tried to load Twitter Bootstrap, "Uncaught Node.js Error"

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, node-webkit

I am a total beginner on node.js, I wanted to experiment with it a bit.

I followed [the instructions on building a node webkit app](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). When I edit index.html, I added `<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>` and it threw the error and displayed a cloud floating around:

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at file:///C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/node-webkit/js/bootstrap.js:158:7
    at file:///C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/node-webkit/js/bootstrap.js:160:2
```

Bootstrap.js:

```
       | +function ($) {
       | ...
ln 158 | $(document).on('click.bs.alert.data-api', dismiss, Alert.prototype.close)
       | ...
ln 160 | }(jQuery);
```

Other than these lines, there are still a bunch of error lines, but it seems to display 2 at a time.

I do not want to invoke any node.js functions or methods, is there something in bootstrap that conflicts with node webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap's requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It seems like you forgot to include it. You should download it and insert `<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` right before where you include `bootstrap.js`.

Comment: didn't forget, loaded an old one. thanks for reminding me to check